# why can't I POST data - Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost, node-modules

I am facing a problem with express [ post request ] :
I created a server-side and client-side code to post data to both the terminal and the browser .. I can't see the result of post function !!

Plz help me, I am in a nightmare

**server.js :**
[image: server code]

**browser result**
[image: browser]

**terminal result**
[image: terminal]

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a result otherwise you won't get anything in the browser.

```js
app.get('/addColor', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send({});
});
```

Comment: I entered : `app.get('/addColor', (req,res) => console.log(req.body);`  as a last line in server.js but it still not work !!  
@warren